# Android Insert new row in between cursor adapter

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 cursor, cursor 1 and cursor 2. A Cursor Adapter has been used to display the result of cursor 1. However, I want to insert cursor 2's item for every 5 cursor 2 items. How can i achieve that?

Currently i have extend a CursorAdapter for the list view for cursor 1. Now I want to insert Cursor 2 items into cursor 1 for every 5 cursor 1's item.

I have look at MatrixCursor and MergeCursor, they would merge and add the rows, but I want to insert in between. Any ideas how can we do this?

Comment: I think you mean you want 1 item from cursor2 for 5 items from cursor1. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes for every 5 item from cursor 1, i want to insert 1 item from cursor 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to understand from your explanation what you want to achieve.
You should extend *BaseAdapter* class because it's easier to adapt for your needs.
This should work for you.

```
public class CursorAdapterTwo extends BaseAdapter{

    private final Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    String[] dataTypes;
    Cursor cursor1;
    Cursor cursor2;


    public CursorAdapterTwo(Context context, Cursor cursor1, Cursor cursor2) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor1 = cursor1;
        this.cursor2 = cursor2;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        cursor1.moveToPosition(position);

        if((position % 5) == 0)
        {
            cursor2.moveToPosition(position / 5);
        }

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout.list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.text_view);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String columnType = dataTypes[position];

        viewHolder.textView.setText("New text");

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if (cursor1 != null) {
            return cursor1.getCount() + cursor2.getCount();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (cursor1 != null) {
            cursor1.moveToPosition(position);
            return cursor1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the getCount be the sum of cursor 1 and 2?  Or perhaps cursor1.count + (cursor1.count / 5) ?